# Warning when attempting a build in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I am getting this error when I attempt to build my project in VS 2010

> Warning   2   Cannot find wrapper assembly
>   for type library "VBIDE".

Anyone experienced this before?  Any ideas what could be the cause?

Comment: Do you have a reference to `VBIDE` in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had that issue as well. I did ended up copying the VBIDE from a peer's machine. It worked fine after that.