# referenced component 'vbide' could not be found vs 2010 on xp

Tags: c#, .net

I have developed (window base c#) projects on Windows 7 with visual studio 2010 and now I want to debug these projects on XP in visual studio 2010. Solution Explorer says I am missing a reference to `vbide`. I found no answers from googling. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please verify my edit didn't change your question. It sounds like you are missing a component on the XP system. Did you install 'vbide' on the XP system?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167545/warning-when-attempting-a-build-in-vs-2010

Comment: NO my question is not changed and i have not install vbide.

Comment: yes i am missing component on xp but how to install this component on xp

Comment: Please tell me how to install vbide on xp  or how to add reference in my solution explore 'vbide'

Answer (score 4):

Remove the old broken reference if one exists then add reference from COM, Select Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility.